# Minecraft weird graphic issue Minecraft 1.13.2

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Hello on this picture you see my weird graphic issue (Watch near door).
I hope someone know how to fix this :)

What i tried to fix this issue:

- Reinstall Minecraft
- Checked if issue only exist in MP (Have this issue in SP too)
- Used Vannila client AND Optifine client (OptiFine 1.13.2 HD UE5 and OptiFine 1.13.2 HD U E4)
- Checked if java is up to date (java is up to date)

[image]
GTX 1060 with driver version 417.71

Comment: Do you mean the thin borders that appear near the crops?

Comment: yes this small thin borders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a really bad case of [MC-1794](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-1794). Some graphics cards are affected, some aren't.

One comment on that report suggests turning off the "mipmapping" options in the video settings as a workaround. I haven't tried this myself.